# Unable to get Supabase user in API route with Next.js

Tags: authentication, next.js, supabase

I followed a tutorial online and my code is pretty similar to that which others have posted here. I am able to get the user from Supabase in `getServerSideProps()` on a page, but I am **not** able to get it in the handler for an api route. This is what I get back from supabase:

```
{
  user: null,
  data: null,
  error: {
    message: 'Invalid token: token contains an invalid number of segments',
    status: 401
  }
}
```

The flow I am doing is to log in using a Supabase magic link, redirect to index page, and then make an API call on the index page. Getting the user is working for me when I authenticate and redirect to the index page. However, when I try to get the user in the API route handler, I get `null`. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
// src/pages/_app.tsx

import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'
import {Provider as ReduxProvider} from 'react-redux'
import {PersistGate} from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import supabase from 'Utilities/SupabaseClient'
import Layout from '../Components/Layout/Layout'
import ModalProvider from '../Components/Modals/ModalProvider/ModalProvider'
import Store, {persistor} from '../Redux/Store'
import 'Components/Shared/Forms/FinalFormCKEditor/style.css'
import './../../public/index.css'

const MyApp = ({Component, pageProps}) => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        const {data: authListener} = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
            handleAuthChange(event, session)
            if (event === 'SIGNED_IN') {
                setIsAuthenticated(true)
                // Do we need to redirect to home?
                router.push('/')
            }
            if (event === 'SIGNED_OUT') {
                setIsAuthenticated(false)
                router.push('/signin')
            }
        })
        checkUser()
        return () => {
            authListener.unsubscribe()
        }
    }, [])

    async function checkUser() {
        const user = await supabase.auth.user()
        if (user) {
            setIsAuthenticated(true)
        }
    }

    async function handleAuthChange(event, session) {
        await fetch('/api/auth', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            body: JSON.stringify({event, session})
        })
    }

    return (
        <ReduxProvider store={Store}>
            <ModalProvider>
                <Layout isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </Layout>
            </ModalProvider>
        </ReduxProvider>
    )
}

export default MyApp

// src/pages/api/board
import prisma from 'Utilities/PrismaClient'
import { supabaseServerClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs'

export default async function handler (req, res) {
  
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    const authObj = await supabaseServerClient({ req, res }).auth.api.getUser(req.cookies["sb-access-token"])

    console.log('authObj: ', authObj)
/*
USROBJ:  {
  user: null,
  data: null,
  error: {
    message: 'Invalid token: token contains an invalid number of segments',
    status: 401
  }
}
*/

    const result = await prisma.board.findMany({
      select: {
        name: true,
        id: true,
        user: true,
        description: true
      }
    })
    console.log(result)
    res.json({ boards: result })
  }

  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const { name, description } = req.body
    const result = await prisma.board.create({
      data: {
        name,
        description,
        user: user.id
      }
    })
    res.status(201).json({ board: result })
  }
}




//src/pages/index.tsx
import React, {PropsWithChildren} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import {getBaseUrl} from 'Utilities'
import supabase from 'Utilities/SupabaseClient'
import {useEffect} from "react"
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux"
import { addAll } from 'Redux/Reducers/BoardSlice'

const Index: React.FC = (props: PropsWithChildren<any>) => {
    const { boards, user } = props
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    console.log('boards: ', boards)

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(addAll({ boards }))
    }, [])

    return (
        <div style={{marginLeft: '46px', fontFamily: 'Roboto'}}>
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <p>Use the main navigation to view your boards or create new ones.</p>
        </div>
    )
}

async function handleAddUser(user, req) {
    const baseUrl = getBaseUrl(req)
    axios.post(`${baseUrl}/api/user`, {user})
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error)
        })
}

async function handleGetBoards(req) {
    return axios.get(`${getBaseUrl(req)}/api/board`)
        .then(({data}) => data.boards)
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}


export async function getServerSideProps({req}) {
    const {user} = await supabase.auth.api.getUserByCookie(req)
    if (!user) {
        return {props: {}, redirect: {destination: '/signin'}}
    }
    await handleAddUser(user, req)
    const boards = await handleGetBoards(req)
    console.log('LINE 52 boards: ', boards)
    return {props: {user, boards}}
}

export default Index




//src/api/auth.js

import supabase from 'Utilities/SupabaseClient'

export default function handler (req, res) {
  supabase.auth.api.setAuthCookie(req, res)
}


//token

{
  "aud": "authenticated",
  "exp": 1664498874,
  "sub": "ccb7113a-bf66-4330-8868-f66a22116216",
  "email": "XXXX@email.com",
  "phone": "",
  "app_metadata": {
    "provider": "email",
    "providers": [
      "email"
    ]
  },
  "user_metadata": {},
  "role": "authenticated",
  "session_id": "157f14a9-f0c0-433d-bc95-9e46d42f488e"
}
```

Comment: Could you try doing ```console.log(req.cookies["sb-access-token"])``` to check if the cookie is set when calling the ```api/board``` route? If it is, is it exactly the cookie you set in ```/api/auth.js```?

Comment: @maxeth I added the following line to the API route: `console.log(`COOKIE_FROM_API:${req.cookies["sb-access-token"]}`)` When I log in to the app using supabase magic link I am redirected to the home page and the aforementioned code logs `undefined`. After I click a `Link` and hit a new page that same call prints out a cookie. The cookie string printed out matches what I see in the developer tools. I guess the question is, why is it sometimes undefined?